# Puppeteer does not run on virtual interface created with netns?

Tags: google-chrome, ip, virtualization, puppeteer

It seems that the puppeteer chrome instance is not started on the virtual interface I created using ip netns. (I run npm on the virtual interface)

What launch parameters do I need?

I launch

```
sudo ip netns exec ns_clt sudo -u [USER] npm start
```

that launches puppeteer.
I tried to add userDataDir

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: true,
  executablePath: 'google-chrome',
  userDataDir: user_data_dir,
});
```

SOLUTION:
Use pipe: true!

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: true,
  executablePath: 'google-chrome',
  userDataDir: user_data_dir,
  pipe: true,
});
```

Comment: You a legend for this one!!!!   Huge help.